# Are 'length' calls rewritten as constant ints by GHC?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Just a random pondering looking at my numerous `length` calls, it occurs to me that surely the compiler can tell the length of *any* list thanks to immutability and referential transparency (even when new lists are `concat`-ed from existing known lists / code paths). Then it will likely replace all `length l` "calls" with the *actual* int constant at some stage during low-level code generation, right?

Wondering if it indeed does, or whether I'm missing something in my beginner intuition about pure functional languages/compiler.

Comment: Show/Tell us more about your code. Are the lists constant?

Comment: Just realizing mine was such a stupid question (break time I guess), of course so many of my lists are strings loaded from IO and entirely dynamic-length. I have to assume a ~25 year-old compiler project will inline known lengths of constant lists..

Comment: That has nothing to do with a 25 year old compiler - it depends on the implementation of the data structure you're using. Lists do not save length information and therefore you don't have constant time length with lists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the question is asking whether GHC turns, for example, `length [1,2,3]` into `3` at compile time. GHC 8.0.1 is the first version of GHC to do this optimization (at least among the versions I have installed).

Now, let's turn to the second part of your question. Let's take the date of the first beta release of GHC from Wikipedia as the beginning date of GHC: April 1, 1991. GHC 8.0.1 was released in May of 2016. So, it appears that your theory that this is an optimization that characterizes 25+ year-old compiler projects is validated in this case.

Comment: WIll it also do this for strings / lists read from files, which aren't known at compile time?

Comment: @Reid Barton well good timing for me then with 8.0.1! The case here with "lists" was really about lots of string processing with many string constants scattered about (predefined formats to generate etc) --- not high-level enough to use advanced text processing packages, but convoluted enough that I noticed I'm doing so many `lengths` on either constants or `concat`s-of-constants, and in deep recursions, and for unknown numbers of in/out files etc that it made me ponder "how constant are my constants at this stage"..

Comment: @ThreeFx unlikely now isn't it? Such predictive powers should be the stuff of the next thing after quantum computing..

Comment: @metaleap, then the bad news for you is it doesn't work for string literals, which have a special desugaring to save space.

Comment: Crikey.. well good to know. Can't believe GHC-output code recurses through a constant "string" (aka sugar-literal) (that's hopefully being put in the DATA section of the assembled binary code) to hit the processor with +1 whenever I pass a constant-desugared-from-a-literal to length directly or indirectly..

Now don't tell me constant strings generate runtime code akin to 'h':['e':['l':['l':['o']]]]

Wonder why the new 8.0.1 optimization isn't timed to occur *after* desugaring of "hello" into ['h','e','l','l','o'] (or whatever is done there)

Comment: So that means internally there's a whole different implementation (in final binary) of length just for constants-desugared-specially-from-string-literals?

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the data structure used. Regular lists are simple singly linked lists:

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
```

You can imagine `length` being defined like this:

```
length []     = 0
length (x:xs) = 1 + length xs
```

This requires O(n) time to run, as there is no faster way to determine the length of this structure.

As the strings reside in a text file, they are not constant at compile time and `length` calls have to be evaluated normally.

---

Using the package [`Data.Vector`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.11.0.0/docs/Data-Vector.html) you get O(1) length calls but lose some list properties.

Comment: I think the question wasn't whats the data structure of List and how to implement length for it, but whether there are any compiler optimisations in cases where the length can be known at compile time.